# Wordpress tax_query ignoring relation OR

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

Yo guys,
I am writing related posts method and I am trying to get all posts that have one or more terms in one or more taxonomies. Here is the sample of what my function spits out:

```
array(
  'post_type' => 
    array (
      0 => string 'post',
      1 => string 'event',
      2 => string 'quiz',
      3 => string 'newsletter'
  ),
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array(...some ids...)
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tax2',
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array(...some ids...)
            )
     )
)
```

The resulting query SQL gives me this:

```
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN 
(58,47,98,75,90,100,101,29,30,102,99,60,52,64,91,44,27) 
AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (5,14,18,22) )
```

It gives me wrong results, namely the only left side of AND passes.

If I change the AND to OR

```
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN 
(58,47,98,75,90,100,101,29,30,102,99,60,52,64,91,44,27) 
OR tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (5,14,18,22) )
```

It returns the desired results!

Does anyone know what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated! I even updated my Wordpress to the latest version!

### UPDATE

I've came up with the not perfect solution to this:

Because I am using `term_taxonomy_id` I can just add all the IDS and remove the taxonomy specification like this:

```
  'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array(...all ids...)
            )
     )
```

And it works! This is a quick solution, although it will work in all of the cases since I can select the desired taxonomies and exclude the non desirable in the process of generation of the query ARGS,

I would still love to know why it was ignoring my `OR relation` in the first place? Is this a bug or I simply do not understand what `OR relation` is meant to be?

Thanks peeps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with the not perfect solution to this:

Because I am using term_taxonomy_id I can just add all the IDS and remove the taxonomy specification like this:

```
  'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array(...all ids...)
            )
     )
```

And it works! This is a quick solution, although it will work in all of the cases since I can select the desired taxonomies and exclude the non desirable in the process of generation of the query ARGS,

I would still love to know why it was ignoring my OR relation in the first place? Is this a bug or I simply do not understand what OR relation is meant to be?